# Find the maximum volume of the pyramid bounded by the plane and the coordinate planes?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, volume, area, plane-curves

Surface

$\sqrt{c}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}$ , $(c>0)$

I found that at $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ a tangent plane to the surface is :

$\frac{x-x_{0}}{2\sqrt{x_{0}}}+\frac{y-y_{0}}{2\sqrt{y_{0}}}+\frac{z-z_{0}}{2\sqrt{z_{0}}}=\sqrt{C}$

a tangent plane and 3 coordinate axes boundes a pyramide (volume $V$)

I'm trying to find  $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ on a surface that gives a maximum value of $V$

Any suggestions or derections ?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to assume that, due to symmetry, the maximum occurs when $x_0=y_0=z_0$?

Comment: See [superellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipsoid) and [superquadric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadrics).

Comment: Yes , can be reasonable while $x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}>0$